# Cannot display cover in gridview with untrusted ssl link

Tags: c#, json, ssl, gridview, uwp

I have a gridview which fetches data from json from localhost.

JSON:
[image: JSON]
For 'cover' on json contains untrusted ssl

Code:

```
string certPath = @"Assets\kc-ssl.p12";
StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(certPath);
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
string certData = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffer);
await CertificateEnrollmentManager.UserCertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
    certData, "Asdf123#", ExportOption.NotExportable, KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
        InstallOptions.None, "kcssl");
var certificate = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(new CertificateQuery() { FriendlyName = "kcssl" });
ClientCert = certificate.Single();
HttpBaseProtocolFilter aHBPF = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
aHBPF.ClientCertificate = ClientCert;
Create our http client and send the request.
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(aHBPF);
Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
pairs.Add("halaman", offset.ToString());
pairs.Add("limit", "16");
pairs.Add("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt");
var formContent = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(urlPath), formContent);
string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
try
{
    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
        JsonObject groupObject1 = jsonObject.GetObject();
    JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();
        foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
    {
        JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();
        string title = groupObject2["judul"].GetString();
        string cover = groupObject2["cover"].GetString();
        Buku file1 = new Buku();
        file1.Judul = title;
        file1.Cover = cover.Replace("http://", "https://");
        datasource.Add(file1);
    }
    itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
}
```

I have a problem, which is unable to display the cover (only blank), as shown below:
[image: Gridview]
How to handle it?

Comment: Could you please tell me if you could get an `Image` instance from the link(“https://...”)?

Comment: Cover is taken from the "cover" link on json by changing http:// to https://

Comment: I assume you want to show images from links(https://) in DataGrid. The possible reason may be relative to the untrusted ssl link, or be relative to the data binding. You could try to get a image from a `https://` link in your scenario to check if the you could get images from these links.

Comment: If I open the "cover" link (https://) in the browser it will appear untrusted ssl and if I click advanced, the "cover" can be opened. But if the "cover" is displayed on the gridview, it will be blank

Comment: I understand what you said. I can’t sure if we could get image from a untrusted ssl link, I haven’t such a ssl link to test. You could use the code   `<Image x:Name="image" Width="200" Height="200"   Source="https://3er1viui9wo30pkxh1v2nh4w-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/prod/2014/08/BillGatesHeadshot-BOD.jpg"/>` and replace the value of `Source` with your untrusted ssl link. If you couldn’t show the image, then maybe it’s not supported to get image from your untrusted ssl link.